# When there is conflict between 2 scriptures which one wins?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, puranas, upanishads, shruti

When there is conflict between 2 scriptures which one wins?

Put followings in order of authority:

Vedas, Upanishads, Smritis, Ramayan, Mahabharat and Puranas

Comment: it's not possible to answer this question satisfactorily, because if I say 'Vedas wins' - you would ask 'who says that?', I would say 'Vedas' - then it becomes a cyclic argument. Whatever is the source of the answer - if that source itself is questioned, then you can never believe it.. anyway, the common answer is - Vedas. But then you don't know Vedas and have to trust whoever knows Vedas. So Itihasa/Puranas help you understand Vedas. Both Shruti and Smriti are like eyes and ears. Cannot understand one without other

Answer (score 2):

The Answer to this is that the Sruti (Veda) is always the highest authority.

Purva Mimamsa sutra Adhyaya 1 Pada 3 directly states that Smriti must be disregarded when it conflicts with the Shruti.

[image]

[image]

To Top it off, The Smriti and the Puranas themselves attest to this fact.

> श्रुतिस्मृतिविरोधे तु श्रुतिरेव गरीयसी
>
> If there is any conflict/contradiction between the Vedas or Smriti,
> only the Vedas shall be upheld.

**~ Jabala Smriti**

Same stated In Vyasa Smriti I.4

> **In Matters of discrepancy between Srutis, smritis and puranas,the
> Srutis should be held as decisive** while the Smritis should have a
> prefence in all topics when there's difference of opinion within
> puranas.

Same thing is reiterated in the Purana as well

> **Where you will find differences between Śruti, Smriti and Purāṇas, accept the words of the Śrutis as final proofs. Wherever Smriti
> disagrees with the Purāṇas, know the Smritis more authoritative.**
>
> **And where differences will crop up in the Śrutis themselves, know that Dharma, too, is of two kinds. And where the differences will crop
> up in the Smritis themselves, consider, then, that different things
> are aimed at.** In some Purāṇas, the Dharma of the Tantras is duly
> described; but of these, which go against the Vedas, they are not to
> be accepted any means.
>
> Tantra is accepted as the authoritative proof then and then only when
> it contradicts not the Vedas. Whatever goes clearly against the Vedas
> can in no way be accepted as a proof. **In matters concerning Dharma,
> the Vedas is the Sole Proof. Therefore that which is not against the
> Vedas can be taken as proof; otherwise not**

**~ Devi bhAgavata 11th Skandha, Chapter 1**

Comment: I have few statements form manusmriti that contradicts mahabharat(for direction of eating) which one to follow?

Comment: What's the contradiction?

Comment: Manu2. 52. (His meal will procure) long life, if he eats facing the east; fame, if he turns to the south; prosperity, if he turns to the west; truthfulness, if he faces the east.

Comment: Somewhere in mahabharat I have read not to eat in west. I don't remember exact verse  and chapter right now. Will send when I find